# Binding Protocols that Conform to Other Protocols

Tags: xamarin.ios

I am trying to bind a protocol using the MonoTouch btouch tool

Objective-C protocol:

```
@protocol KalDataSource <NSObject, UITableViewDataSource>
- (void)presentingDatesFrom:(NSDate *)fromDate to:(NSDate *)toDate delegate:(id<KalDataSourceCallbacks>)delegate;
- (NSArray *)markedDatesFrom:(NSDate *)fromDate to:(NSDate *)toDate;
- (void)loadItemsFromDate:(NSDate *)fromDate toDate:(NSDate *)toDate;
- (void)removeAllItems;
@end
```

BTouch Binding:

```
[BaseType(typeof(UITableViewDataSource)]
interface KalDataSource {
    ...
}
```

But this results in the btouch error:

```
error CS0534: `Kal.KalDataSource' does not implement inherited abstract member...
```

Where the missing members are, of course, GetCell and RowsInSection. I thought of creating a partial class implementation of KalDataSource but still need to make it virtual for consumers to define those methods. Halp?

**Update:** After clarification it seems it is not immediately possible to bind protocols that "inherit" from other UIKit protocols. I have filed a bug here:

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=3526

Comment: what's your exact command line ? I tried something similar without an issue (once I added the missing `)` in the attribute)

Comment: Hmm, interesting...which attribute am I missing? Makefile for build: https://gist.github.com/c40dc80b0253fd93d30b

Comment: no missing *attribute* - just a missing closing *parenthesis* ;-) and it worked for me (and likely Miguel too) because I added it to my monotouch build (for a quick test)

Answer (score 0):

With recent versions of btouch, you can list protocols you implement, in this case, like this:

```
[BaseType (typeof (NSObject))]
interface KalDataSource : UITableViewDataSource {
}
```

Notice that this is using [BaseType] with NSObject which will be its subclass, and instead will inline the methods from the UITableViewDataSource.

Comment: I posted the same thing, bad search I guess... 

I solved the problem by redefining the second interface within the ApiDefinition.cs file, so t